# learning Objective C,iphone

Tags: iphone

In Android we can use intent to send (putextras) and receive (getextras) from 1 to another activity. I would like to ask there are any techniques like this in Iphone because I want to send a content of UITextField from  First.m to Second.m
All comments are welcomed here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSNotifications.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

hey try this tutirial hope it helps:
[here](http://gregorykaiser.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/385/)

and 
[here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/downloads.php)

Comment: The second link is broken though. Can you send it again and thanks for your help too